# R glm object and prediction using offsets

Tags: r, logistic-regression

So I'm using R to do logistic regression, but I'm using offsets.

```
  mylogit <- glm(Y ~  X1 + offset(0.2*X2) + offset(0.4*X3), data = test, family = "binomial")
```

The output, shows only a single coefficient, the intercept and one of the predictors, X1.

```
    Coefficients:
    (Intercept)               X1
      0.5250748         0.0157259
```

My question:  How do i get the raw prediction from each observation from this model?
More specifically, if I use the predict function, will it include all the features and their coefficients, even though the model coefficients are listed as only containing the intercept and X1?

```
  prob = predict(mylogit,test,type=c("response"))
```

Do I have to use the predict function?  Does the "mylogit" object contain anything I can compute directly from? (yes I looked at the documentation on glm, still confused).

thank you for your patients.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can report the results of some experiments with `glm` and `offset()`. It does not appear (at least from this experiment) that your call to `predict` will give results that take the `offset` into account. Rather it seems that `summary.glm` is needed for that purpose. I started with a rather mangled modification of the 1st example in `?glm` ( and this would  be more pertinent to your concerns if you did provide data, because then we could play around more with the newdata argument that you would need for "test".)

```
counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
treatment <- gl(3,3)
print(d.AD <- data.frame(treatment, outcome, counts))
glm.D93 <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment + offset(1:9), family = poisson())
glm.D93d <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment , family = poisson())

> predict(glm.D93d, type="response")
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9 
21.00000 13.33333 15.66667 21.00000 13.33333 15.66667 21.00000 13.33333 15.66667 
> predict(glm.D93, type="response")
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9 
21.00000 13.33333 15.66667 21.00000 13.33333 15.66667 21.00000 13.33333 15.66667
```

As far as I can tell the `offset` is only apparent when comparisons of the estimated coefficients are made to the NULL estimate (usually 0) for the purposes of statistical inference. That is done by `summary.glm`:

```
> summary(glm.D93)$coef
             Estimate Std. Error    z value      Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  2.044522  0.1708987  11.963362  5.527764e-33
outcome2    -1.454255  0.2021708  -7.193203  6.328878e-13
outcome3    -2.292987  0.1927423 -11.896644  1.232021e-32
treatment2  -3.000000  0.2000000 -15.000000  7.341915e-51
treatment3  -6.000000  0.2000000 -30.000000 9.813361e-198
> summary(glm.D93d)$coef
                 Estimate Std. Error       z value     Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  3.044522e+00  0.1708987  1.781478e+01 5.426767e-71
outcome2    -4.542553e-01  0.2021708 -2.246889e+00 2.464711e-02
outcome3    -2.929871e-01  0.1927423 -1.520097e+00 1.284865e-01
treatment2   1.337909e-15  0.2000000  6.689547e-15 1.000000e+00
treatment3   1.421085e-15  0.2000000  7.105427e-15 1.000000e+00
```

The offset is only changing the reference levels (with fairly bizarre changes in this mangled example) while the fitting of `$linear.predictors` and `$fitted` to the data is not affected. I didn't see a comment in glm that affects this but there is a comment in `?lm` : "Offsets specified by offset will not be included in predictions by predict.lm, whereas those specified by an offset term in the formula will be." I will admit that I got very little insight from reading `?model.offset`.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive response, I'll review this and look into it.  I think actually the model does take them into account, as when I manual do it, it reports the same answer. I'll get my code together and place it here. thx!

Comment: I don't really consider this "comprehensive". I have been a user of "offset" in selected situations, but I admit that I'm not entirely sure about how it is working. I was frankly surprised by some of my "experimental" findings.

Comment: Does this answer really answer the question? I'm experiencing similar difficulties as OP.

Comment: Which question? How similar? (I think you probably need to construct a [MCVE] and post a new question.)